# How to automatically assign ULA via SLAAC?

Tags: macos, ipv6, slaac

I have an OpenBSD router configured to send GUA and ULA prefixes in Router Advertisements. I can see that both prefixes in packet captures but only a GUA address is assigned.

Is there something I need to do on the MacOS side to configure the ULA or should it do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the prefix to a /64 and that "fixed" it. It's now assigning both ULA and GUA.